# Center text optically in UILabel

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, text-alignment

I would like to center text in UILabel. The problem is that using the standard alignment (i.e. setting `UILabel.textAlignment` to `.center`) is not enough:
[image]

As you can see, the "stem" of number 1 is mostly in the right half, so the whole symbol looks slightly shifted to the right. To fix this I would need to find the optical center and adjust the alignment accordingly. If the text was static, I would find and apply the offset by trial and error, but obviously such approach does not work if the text can change in runtime.

Of course, I could calculate the offset for the most common values, but is there a generic way to calculate the optical center of text in runtime?

Comment: What about a sans-serif font?

Comment: This is most likely the font itself — if you find a monospace font that centers each character in its frame, that won't happen.

Comment: @brandonscript that might do the trick, but let's say I want this label to use the same font as the rest of UI.

Comment: The system centers the font frame, and the frame of that particular font's 1 does not place much kerning on the right to offset its tail. If you want to use that font, you'll have to manually offset it — there's no way to make the system magically detect what "visually centered" would be.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've done that myself with certain fonts: detect numbers that don't center visually, and offset the constraints.

Comment: @brandonscript and by "detect numbers" you mean doing it yourself, right?

Comment: Yes. E.g., a dict with a range of numbers and points to offset by: `[{1: -0.5, 15: -0.6}]`. There's probably a more efficient way of doing it, but it was a few years back, and I was lazy. You could also design your own algorithm that identifies certain chars, their offsets, and what you'd need to do if a number began, ended, or both began & ended with specific numbers.